# Concatenate pandas dataframes. Preserve multiindex levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Tried many things before asking here. Appreciate any help.

I have two data frames that are the product of the aggregate function that I would like to merge together and be able to sort them based on the multi-index levels.

Here is what the look like:

```
       Serial   year     quarter  min      median     mean          max  
0   #474331000  2014        2   2350000   2350000  2.350000e+06   2350000   
1   #484110AD1  2014        2    185000    185000  1.850000e+05    185000   
2   #484114BA0  2014        2    126000    126000  1.260000e+05    126000 

     Serial    year    quarter    min   median     mean      max          
0  #484118020  2015        1      100      100      100      100            
1  #484119AF0  2015        1   160000   165250   165250   170500     
2  #484121AG0  2015        1   120000   120000   120000   120000
```

I'd like to merge them together to get something resembling this:

```
          y2014    y2014     y2014   y2015   y2015  y2015
            2q       2q       2q      1q      1q    1q
            min     median    mean   median mean    min
Serials                     
#3843442115  600     1,148   1,171   2,100   364    40
#5243420535  1,100   1,375   1,359   1,650   169    33
#0843451718  1,100   1,450   1,429   1,750   178    27
#7442431510  750     950     975     1,200   112    24
#7443431921  775     925     972     1,300   155    23
#7442431323  700     950     925     1,100   97     21
```

Ultimately i'd like to be able to select out the results by metric, year, quarter and plot their change over time.

Right now there is a simple index on the data frames and I think that tagging each column with the year and quarter labels as seen above may or may not require a multi index.

After setting the index, I could't find a way to merge the data frames to give the desired result.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to help me merge, query and sort data frames on the (year,quarter,metric) multi index levels?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

Raw input based on your data:

```
>>> df1
       Serial  year  quarter      min   median       mean      max
0  #474331000  2014        2  2350000  2350000  2350000.0  2350000
1  #484110AD1  2014        2   185000   185000   185000.0   185000
2  #484114BA0  2014        2   126000   126000   126000.0   126000
>>> df2
       Serial  year  quarter     min  median    mean     max
0  #484118020  2015        1     100     100     100     100
1  #484119AF0  2015        1  160000  165250  165250  170500
2  #484121AG0  2015        1  120000  120000  120000  120000
```

Transform them in to the multi-index columns you're looking for

```
>>> df1_transformed = df1.set_index(['Serial', 'year', 'quarter']).unstack().unstack()
>>> df2_transformed = df2.set_index(['Serial', 'year', 'quarter']).unstack().unstack()
>>> df1_transformed
                min   median       mean      max
quarter           2        2          2        2
year           2014     2014       2014     2014
Serial
#474331000  2350000  2350000  2350000.0  2350000
#484110AD1   185000   185000   185000.0   185000
#484114BA0   126000   126000   126000.0   126000
>>> df2_transformed
               min  median    mean     max
quarter          1       1       1       1
year          2015    2015    2015    2015
Serial
#484118020     100     100     100     100
#484119AF0  160000  165250  165250  170500
#484121AG0  120000  120000  120000  120000
```

You can use `df1_transformed.reorder_levels([2,1,0], axis=1)` to get the order of column index you like, but I'm leaving that out for simplicity.

Finally combine them:

```
>>> final = pd.concat([df1_transformed, df2_transformed], axis=1)
>>> final
                  min     median       mean        max       min    median  \
quarter             2          2          2          2         1         1
year             2014       2014       2014       2014      2015      2015
#474331000  2350000.0  2350000.0  2350000.0  2350000.0       NaN       NaN
#484110AD1   185000.0   185000.0   185000.0   185000.0       NaN       NaN
#484114BA0   126000.0   126000.0   126000.0   126000.0       NaN       NaN
#484118020        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN     100.0     100.0
#484119AF0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  160000.0  165250.0
#484121AG0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  120000.0  120000.0

                mean       max
quarter            1         1
year            2015      2015
#474331000       NaN       NaN
#484110AD1       NaN       NaN
#484114BA0       NaN       NaN
#484118020     100.0     100.0
#484119AF0  165250.0  170500.0
#484121AG0  120000.0  120000.0
```

Since your raw input data do not have overlapping Serial numbers, the final matrix has many `NaN`s. In the case they do have overlapping Serial numbers, they the `NaN`s will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just set the column names, and you'll have them in the form above.

```
result.columns=[['year']*6,['quarter']*6,['min','median','mean','max','std','count']]
```

Later you can slice based on those column names.